# Wordpress Permalinks resulting in 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I cannot seem to get my permalinks working for my WordPress site.

My WordPress homepage, and wp-admin work fine, just none of my sub-pages work.

I've been mucking about with my .htaccess file, and site.conf files, but I cannot seem to get this working.

For context, I have the following file structure:

```
Root
|--.htaccess
|--wordpress
|--|--index.php
```

Path: `/var/www/html/domain.ca/public_html/wordpress`

Here is my current .htaccess config:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.ca$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.ca$
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And here is my current site.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email@email.com
        ServerName domain.ca
        ServerAlias www.domain.ca
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.ca/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/html/domain.ca/public_html>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride All
               Require all granted
        </Directory>

        LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I've already tried going into wp-admin and re-saving permalinks, that simply makes things worse as it seems to default my .htaccess to one that is designed for WordPress installed in root, and not a sub directory.

I've also ensured that mod_rewrite is enabled in Apache, and I have rebooted the server.

Comment: Can you give us the apache and php version please?

Comment: Not sure if you want example.com/wordpress to work or if you want to run example.com in the wordpress directory without displaying it in url

Comment: @gael, the latter, I'm wanting people to hit domain.ca, instead of domain.ca/wordpress

Comment: @Benjamin PHP v7.2.19 Apache2 v2.4.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Virtualhost is good and you should keep default wp .htaccess as it is generated automatically as soon as you set the permalinks (at least between the 2 commented lines `#BEGIN` and `#END WordPress`)

Quoted from https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-ii-with-url-change

I guess points 1, 5 and 10 are already done for you but it might help future readers to.

1. Create the new location for the core WordPress files to be stored
   (we will use /wordpress in our examples). (On linux, use mkdir
   wordpress from your www directory. You’ll probably want to use chown
   apache:apache on the wordpress directory you created.)
2. Go to the General Screen.
3. In WordPress address (URL): set the address of your main WordPress
   core files. Example: http://example.com/wordpress
4. In Site address (URL): set root directory’s URL. Example:
   http://example.com
5. Now move your WordPress core files (from root directory) to the
   subdirectory.
6. Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the
   WordPress directory into the root directory of your site (Blog
   address). The .htaccess file is invisible, so you may have to set
   your FTP client to show hidden files. If you are not using pretty
   permalinks, then you may not have a .htaccess file. If you are
   running WordPress on a Windows (IIS) server and are using pretty
   permalinks, you’ll have a web.config rather than a .htaccess file in
   your WordPress directory. For the index.php file the instructions
   remain the same, copy (don’t move) the index.php file to your root
   directory. The web.config file, must be treated differently than the
   .htaccess file so you must MOVE (DON’T COPY) the web.config file to
   your root directory.
7. Open your root directory’s index.php file in a text editor
8. Change the following and save the file. Change the line that
   says:require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );to the
   following, using your directory name for the WordPress core
   files:require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php'
   );
9. Login to the new location. It might now be http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/
10. If you have set up Permalinks, go to the Permalinks Screen and
     update your Permalink structure. WordPress will automatically
     update your .htaccess file if it has the appropriate file
     permissions. If WordPress can’t write to your .htaccess file, it
     will display the new rewrite rules to you, which you should
     manually copy into your .htaccess file (in the same directory as
     the main index.php file.)

Comment: Ok, so, initial impressions are that steps 6-9 helped, and things seem to be working again. However, I can't understand why. These steps were never required before this issue occurred, but I'm not complaining ... I'm going to give it a day or so to ensure all is well, then you will get my vote for accepted solution ... Thanks!

Comment: I thank you too because I read it was a good practice to host WordPress in a subdirectory. And now I know how to do it 